# How can I check if a specific AWS service is healthy in a specific region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been trying to check if an AWS service is available/healthy in a specific region.

I have been using aws provided endpoints for example for lambda: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html`

I am able to get a proper response for some resources like DynamoDB. Whenever I hit the endpoint `http://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` I get the response:

> healthy: dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

But when I try for resources like Lambda `https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` I get:

```
<MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
  <Message>Missing Authentication Token</Message>
</MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
```

Any way I could get a healthy or unhealthy response?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite rare that an AWS service is unhealthy. You can see system status at: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

You should be accessing those API endpoints by using the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), not by simply accessing that URL in a browser.